# Is it possible to disable showing `-- VISUAL LINE --` hint in the command line?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, neovim, lua

As title: I have a plugin that needs to show something in cmdline but now the space is occupied by:

```
-- VISUAL LINE --
```

Any hint to get rid of it?

Comment: `:h 'showmode'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn it off by:

```
:set noshowmode
```

Comment: Finally, I realized that this is the option I thought I would never need to use it the future.